# Where are all the Alcarnus prisoners?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The Hero of Alcarnus achievement says to find all 13 prisoners in Alcarnus. I've found 10 in the main bazaar area. Where are the other three?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the other prisoners inside the buildings. You'll have a couple of "dungeon" entrances in the bazar area. Inside the one in the lower part of the map you'll find a group of enemies and the prisoners you're looking for.

Comment: Would that mean if not all random dungeons spawn, you're unable to get the achievement (in that run)?

Comment: @IvoFlipse You'll always find the whole 13 of them around Alcarnus, divided randomly among the available "dungeons". On my first run I got 2 rooms in which to search, one with no prisoners, the other with all of those that were still missing.

Comment: That's a reassuring thought then +1

Comment: Actually the one with 3 prisoners to the north of the lower part of the Alcarnus map is always there. There's nothing random about it.